# Installing scikits.bvp_solver

Tags: python, scipy, enthought, scikits, canopy

I need to use scikits.bvp_solver in python.
I currently use Canopy as my standard Python interface, where this package isn't available. Is there another available package for solving boundary value problems? I have also tried downloading using macports but the procedure sticks when it tries building gcc48 dependency.

Comment: platform? In general, you can install any external package into Canopy: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-Python-from-the-command-line

Comment: I have managed to install it using macports, after waiting for a long time to install the gcc dependancy. But even now I can import it neither from canopy nor from the standard python terminal. I cannot find it using sys.modules. There might be something wrong about the Port installation. 
But even if I try to Easy_install it or  manually install it the installation fails!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download the package tar.gz and use easy_install . Or you can unpack the package and use the standard way of python setup.py install. I believe both ways require a fortran compiler.